# How to access a server-generated message in a jquery script in an EJS page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I would like to access a variable passed to an EJS page from a controller in a jQuery script.

Here's my controller method.

```
app.get('/form', (req, res) => {
    res.render('form', {
        errorMessage: 'aaaaa'
    });
}
```

Here's my EJS page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="reset-form" method="POST">
      <div class="passwordError"></div>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required />
      <input type="password" id="confirm_password" required>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset Password">
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
      console.log(<%= errorMessage %>)
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I access errorMessage in my jQuery script? I've tried

```
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        console.log(errorMessage)
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

But I just get the error message 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: aaaaa is not defined`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap errorMessage in EJS tags

```
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        console.log("<%=errorMessage%>")
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that but I got an Uncaught ReferenceError that seemed to think that the string was a variable name

Comment: That'll do it. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help, it would be good if you could accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap my embedded javascript in quotes like so

```
console.log("<%= errorMessage %>")
```